# How and what to test by using respectively Cucumber and Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, cucumber

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2, cucumber-rails-1.3.0, rspec-rails-2.8.1 and capybara-1.1.2 with the Selenium driver. I would like to know ***how* and *what* to test by using respectively Cucumber and Rspec?** That is, what "behavior" should I treat with Cucumber and what with Rspec so to divide testing "concerns" in a proper way?

*For example*, in order to test a view, should I test the presence of a CSS `id` in a page content by using Cucumber or RSpec? or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RSpec to test the various parts(Controllers, Models and Views) of your app by isolating them. (with Mock, Stub and the others tools that gives you RSpec)

Use Cucumber to test all parts of your app togheter, as you see the app in the browser... for example, if you need to test the sign in form of your app without cucumber you should:

1) Open a shell and run rails server.

2) Go to browser and type the url of login.

3) Fill in form fields.

4) Click Submit button.

You should automate this process, and similar process with Cucumber, for others test use Rspec.

Comment: I would like to testJavaScript behavior too. Should I use *exclusively* Cucumber for those things?

Comment: Cucumber use [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) for test, that has support for javascript and ajax request with Selenium.

Comment: My "sub-question" (in the previous comment) was emphasizing the **exclusively** word. That is (in other words), in order to test JavaScript, should I use *only* Cucumber or I *should* use RSpec too?

Comment: Sorry, I had not realized... I personally do not test only Javascript code, but some people use [Jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine) for that, has a plugin for use in Rspec(is applied the global rule: Js is only a part of an app, then should use Rspec)

Comment: I have a doubt, so I open a new question: [Should I use the Selenium ruby-gem or the Jasmine ruby-gem in order to test view files with RSpec?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969817/should-i-use-the-selenium-ruby-gem-or-the-jasmine-ruby-gem-in-order-to-test-view)

Answer (score 0):

They both can test for node attributes, but I would use Capybara only for request specs. Ultimately it is personal preference. I use rspec and capybara together, but the language syntax of capybara makes more sense/is semantic as rspec when testing for request/expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Use UnitTest & capybara for testing because its more simple and fast. Checkout this URL for more details.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html