# Should I use Selenium or Jasmine in order to test view files with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec, jasmine

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2, cucumber-rails-1.3.0, rspec-rails-2.8.1 and capybara-1.1.2 with the Selenium driver. After receiving the answer to a my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906352/how-and-what-to-test-by-using-respectively-cucumber-and-rspec) I had a doubt: *should I use the Selenium ruby-gem or the Jasmine ruby-gem in order to test view files with RSpec?* If so, since I am already using Selenium in order to test JavaScript for view files with Cucumber, *why* (when testing with RSpec) should I use Jasmine instead of Selenium? That is, why to use two ruby-gems that have the same purpose and make the same things?

Generally and practically speaking, **how do you advice to test view files by using RSpec? ... but, is it the "right way" to test view files with RSpec or should I test those by using Cucumber?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use selenium server, the selenium IDE in firefox to record and selenium client for rspec.

selenium_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'../..','config','environment'))
require 'spec/autorun'
require 'spec/rails'
require 'factory_girl'
require 'rspec/instafail'
require "selenium/client"

Spec::Runner.configure do |config|
end
```

rspec_tester_file_spec.rb

```
  require "selenium/selenium_helper"
    require "selenium/modules/loginator"

    describe "tester" do
      attr_reader :selenium_driver
      alias :page :selenium_driver

      before(:all) do
        @verification_errors = []
        @selenium_driver = Selenium::Client::Driver.new \
          :host => "localhost",
          :port => 4444,
          :browser => "*firefox",
          :url => "http://localhost:3000",
          :timeout_in_second => 60
      end

      before(:each) do
        @selenium_driver.start_new_browser_session
      end

      append_after(:each) do
        @selenium_driver.close_current_browser_session
      end

      it "login and then try to search for stuff" do
        @login.run_login(page)
        page.click "link=CSR"
        page.wait_for_page_to_load "30000"
        page.type "id=isq_Name", "john smith"
        page.click "css=input[type=\"submit\"]"
        page.wait_for_page_to_load "30000"
        page.is_text_present("Update")
        page.is_text_present("Date")
        page.is_text_present("PIN")      
        page.is_text_present("Name")
      end
```

Comment: I would like to also add, that I do use jasmine but only for javascript testing and never for view based testing. Furthermore, if I have a javascript function which can be tested with jasmine then I will, but not when it is altering UI elements. UI elements I check with selenium.